# Initializing Layout Variables in Module.php using ZF2 and TWIG

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twig

Good day,

I have a twig layout template with contents of the ZF2 skeleton (zfctwig version) and I want to have a dynamic main navigation using a variable that I will set in module.config.php.

layout.twig:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav">
   {% for item in navigation %}

    <li {% if item.active %} class="active" {% endif %}>
       <a href="{{ url(item.route) }}">
       {{ translate(item.name) }}
       </a>
    </li>

   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I will pass it using the onBootstrap() method in my Module.php:

Module.php:

```
$navigation = array(
   'home' => array(
      'name' => 'Home',
      'route' => 'home',
   ),
   'profile' => array(
      'name' => 'Profile',
      'route' => 'myroute',
      'active' => true
   ),
);

$view = $e->getApplication('application')->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();

$view->navigation = $navigation;
```

The $navigation variable will be placed in my module.config.php after I got this working.

This code works when I'm not using twig in my template (e.g. layout.phtml with no twig codes) but when I am using the above layout.twig, {{navigation}} is empty.

I think that I should not be using

```
$view = $e->getApplication('application')->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
```

since I think it returns the default zf2 ViewModel and not the twig version but I don't know how it's retrieved.

If this is not the problem, what am I doing wrong? and if I got it working, how can I change the active index of $navigation['profile'] to false in one of my controllers?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:**

It seems that nobody had experience the same problem. Am I doing this the wrong way? Is there a better way to do this? The goal is to create a dynamic main menu and navigation that can be modified using the settings inside a module.config.php rather than updating the view file constantly. Changing it in a specific controller is not good either since I want it to be global since the main menu will be the same on every page. I searched the web but I can't find a way to do it using twig.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sm->get('ZfcTwigRenderer');
```

Use this code to access twig renderer

example :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $ZfcTwigRenderer = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcTwigRenderer');


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm a little lost, should I place this in my Module.php on method onBootstrap()? how can I get the service manager there? Sorry I'm new to ZF. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't work. Is $ZfcTwigRenderer->navigation = $navigation; enough or I need to call a method to set it?

Comment: where do you use $ZfcTwigRenderer->navigation in your templates?  in layout or in template?  syntax going to be different

Comment: I'm using it inside onBootstrap(). After $ZfcTwigRenderer = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ZfcTwigRenderer'); I call $ZfcTwigRenderer->navigation = $navigation.

Comment: No changes in my layout.twig code above. I just changed the contents of my onBootstrap() method in my Module.php to reflect your answer but I still have the same problem. I really appreciate your reply. Thank you very much!